# Enlarge /boot Filesystem

Tags: boot, partitioning

I have Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS running on a HP microserver, no desktop or GUI.
I have installed Gparted Live on a USB drive and booted to that. My plan was to reduce the size of /dev/sda2 about 750MB then increase /boot by that same amount. Problem is I can only reduce /dev/sda2 by about 3 MB, and I can't even increase /dev/sda1 by that?
Is this possible? or do I need to repartition the drive and install ubuntu again?

[Gparted ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ALd6S.jpg)

This is result from df

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            930M  4.0K  930M   1% /dev
tmpfs           188M  800K  187M   1% /run
/dev/dm-0       228G   19G  198G   9% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            939M  4.0K  939M   1% /run/shm
none            100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
/dev/sda1       228M  215M  935K 100% /boot
/dev/md0        1.8T  1.1T  634G  64% /raid1
```

Any Help most appreciated....Thanks!

Comment: With that layout, you're not going to be able to extend `/dev/sda1`.

Comment: So I have to start again?

Comment: depends. You might be able to reconfigure grub to not use a separate boot partition at all, and just ignore the existing one.

Comment: You might also just try clearing some of the space in `/boot` - please see [https://askubuntu.com/questions/89710/how-do-i-free-up-more-space-in-boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89710/how-do-i-free-up-more-space-in-boot)